# .css hide empty dt and dd elements

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to hide all dt and dd emelments which have the class `empty`

[image]

How can I do this with a custom .css file 
I can not access the elements so far ;(

Comment: `.empty { display: none; }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just use `.empty { display: none; }` to achieve the result you are after. This will hide everything that has the class of `.empty`

Comment: I am pretty sure that I tried this before, nevertheless is works :)